# System to register dates

Tags: web-apps, reservation

I'm working at a university where a lot of students have to give a small presentation regularly (10 minutes each, around 300-500 students).
Our current system is to have lists where each student has to register manually each week. I think you can imagine how well this works …

This is why I want to create a website where all possible time slots are listed and the students can select one of those to register for the date. I don't want to build something from scratch, I'm pretty sure that something similar already exists which I only have to tune, but I have no idea where to look for it.

My requirements:

- students can register and see later on which date they registered (possibly even change afterwards?)
- the new "lists" should be easy to create, we have to give out new dates every week
- no special selection method is needed, just first come first serve
- after the registration I need a table / calendar etc. sorted by date where I can see easily who is next

I do not care if it is PHP or something else.

Comment: Self-hosted, hosted, or both?

Comment: @unor: preferably self hosted but I am grateful for any solution.

Comment: Are you saying you have time slots of 10 minutes, for some number of hours on certain dates, and you want each student to assign themselves to one of those 10 minute slots? How do control users, stop some bozo from filling slots with fake people?

Answer (score 1):

All of this should be possible with [Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/), which is to my knowledge the most elaborate opens source resource scheduling / booking application.

Some hints for how to use it for this case:

- Create one schedule only.
- Adapt the schedule layout to have 10 minute time slots (or longer if you also have Q&A / gaps).
- Create one resource "Presentation". This means that it can be booked only once in parallel.
- Set both minimum and maximum duration to "10 minutes" for your "Presentation" resource.
- Let all students register accounts and then book the spot they want. Or even allow booking without accounts.

If you find two calendar views that allow booking, only keep the FullCalendar based version. That's the newer / more modern one.